# Who is the Bounty Hunter on the Star Wars: The Old Republic loading screen?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I think I know who all of the other characters are, but I'm stumped on the - or what appears to be - female Bounty Hunter.

[A link to the image in question.](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ikYCEgquIPI/TuDw2DlO-SI/AAAAAAAAAEY/JFfIrH5htOk/s1600/wallpaper_star_wars_the_old_republic_04_2560x1440.jpg)

Comment: I think it's just a generic Mandalorian.

Comment: She may be, but it just seems odd given that all the other figures are known...even the droid :)

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the novel "The Old Republic: Deceived", her name is Shae Vizla, though Malgus often refers to her simply as "The Mandalorian".

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shae_Vizla

It's fitting that she's named since she single-handedly shut down Coruscant's defense grid and also took part in the attack on Alderaan :)

Malgus probably chose her for the attack since she had a very deep-seated hatred of the Jedi because her brother was killed by Jedi Master Aurei Eadon.

Answer (score -1):

She's the Mandalorean Mercenary featured in the [Imperial intro movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g4e4PXOIlY). I don't think she's ever named.